# What is the relation between $x,y$ if $\tan(20^\circ),x,\tan(50^\circ)$ and $\tan(20^\circ),y,\tan(70^\circ)$ are in AP?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

If $\tan(20°),x,\tan(50°)$ are in AP and $\tan(20°),y,\tan(70°)$ are in AP then relation between x and y is?. $$\text{Attempt}$$. As they are in AP  So $2x=\tan(20°)+\tan(50°),2y=\tan(20°)+\tan(70°)$ now I divide these two to get $$\frac{x}{y}=\frac{\tan(20°)+tan(50°)}{\tan(20°)+tan(70°)}$$ . How to simplify RHS. Now its all in tan so I won't be surprised if we have any interesting identity there!.Thanks!

Comment: Is there something incorrect with just converting it in $\cos$ and $\sin$ and then using $\cos(x + y) = \cos(x)\cos(y) \cdots$ same for $\sin$.

Comment: Are you sure ? won't it be a horrible expression to simplify

Comment: I can do it mentally and you say it is horrible to simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $\tan A+\tan B=\cdots=\dfrac{\sin(A+B)}{\cos A\cos B},$

$$\dfrac{\sin(20^\circ+50^\circ)}{\cos20^\circ\cos50^\circ}\cdot\dfrac{\cos20^\circ\cos70^\circ}{\sin(20^\circ+70^\circ)}$$

$$=\dfrac{\sin70^\circ\cos70^\circ}{\cos50^\circ}$$

$$=\dfrac{\sin140^\circ}{2\sin(90^\circ-50^\circ)}$$

$$=\dfrac{\sin(180^\circ-40^\circ)}{2\sin40^\circ}=?$$

Comment: Thanks can you just tell me how did you get that idea

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, For the simplification the first line is obvious right ?

Comment: Okay got it ...

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\tan(70^\circ)=\tan(20^\circ+50^\circ)=\frac{\tan(20^\circ)+\tan(50^\circ)}{1-\tan(20^\circ)\tan(50^\circ)}$$
Since
$$\tan(70^\circ)\tan(20^\circ)=\tan (70^\circ)\cot(70^\circ)=1$$
we have
$$\tan(70^\circ)(1-\tan(20^\circ)\tan(50^\circ))=\tan(20^\circ)+\tan(50^\circ)$$
$$\implies \tan (70^\circ)=\tan(20^\circ)+2\tan(50^\circ)$$
$$\implies 2y-\tan(20^\circ)=\tan(20^\circ)+2(2x-\tan(20^\circ))\implies \color{red}{y=2x}$$

Comment: $$\cot A-\tan A=2\cot2A$$  Put $A=20^\circ$